# Prestashop sales using social network

Tags: prestashop, facebook-social-plugins

I have a question about the Prestashop sales when using social network for this.

I need to know if when there is a sale in prestashop and this sale was for advertesing of facebook, this action is registered in any place in prestashop?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean if you can see where the sales link is coming from? If I am right, your answer is yes. Prestashop1.7.6 will show you referral links. you can also buy a module for this.

if I didn't understand your question, please, re-frame it.